How to find unused services on AWS?
I have been given admin of an AWS account and have used AWS Resource Explorer to check what resources there are, the Tag Editor list everything the can be tagged (previous users weren't careful with tags, but it lists things without tags) and the IAM access tracker to watch what was being used. I thought I had a good handle on everything.
But then AWS emailed about a Simple AD resource that needed key rotation. It had been setup in 2017 and wasn't used (probably an experiment). As I didn't have permissions to view AWS Simple AD (I don't use root but can give myself perms if needed) so it didn't appear in the Tag Editor.
[Edit] I have temporarily given myself the IAM AdministratorAccess policy and now can see everything on AWS but still keen to know if...
Is there a better way to view all the resources and settings without going into Tag Editor as root?

Look in cost explorer, that will tell you what AWS is charging you for. Use the filters like grouping by usage (it's one of the dropdowns near the top of the page on the right), that makes it simpler to understand.
